# What is the command to download all the gems corresponding to an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 2.3.5

I would like to download all the gems corresponding a new application I cloned.

I can't remember the command.

Comment: By "download" do you mean download somewhere without installing or are you just looking for the Rails 2.3 equivalent of `bundle install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to install all gems specified in `environment.rb`:

```
rake gems:install
```

You can always use this to see all tasks

```
rake -T
```

Comment: and rake gems:unpack to vendor them